# How can a query with a TOP 10 take infinitely longer to complete than the same query without the TOP 10?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, user-defined-functions

I have a very simple situation:

I have a Table Valued Function called  `FullTextPagina` defined as follows:

```
select * from Pagina as p where contains(p.PageText, @term)
```

And then I have 2 queries:

```
declare @term nvarchar(4000)= N'"DIEGO NUNES J COMBINADO"'

SELECT Id, DtPagina
FROM FullTextPagina(@term)
ORDER BY DtPagina DESC

SELECT TOP 10 Id, DtPagina
FROM FullTextPagina(@term)
ORDER BY DtPagina DESC
```

They are identical except for the fact that the second includes a `TOP 10` statement. And they don't return anything. 0 rows.

**The first executes instantly. The seconds takes 1:20m to complete.**

Why?

PS:

1. I have correctly set up the full-text index
2. I have a non-clustered, non-unique descending index on `DtPagina`
3. The execution plan is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYb0I.png

---

**EDIT**

Responding to @MartinSmith, curiously, the "Number of Executions" for the Table Valued Functions is 1.18 million for the TOP 10 case and 1 for the other case

**EDIT 2**

Execution plan XML
http://tecnologia.novaprolink.com.br/Execution%20plan.xml

**EDIT 3**

Adding option(recompile) or taking off the parameters don't affect the result

```
SELECT Id, DtPagina
FROM FullTextPagina(N'"DIEGO NUNES J COMBINADO"')
ORDER BY DtPagina DESC

SELECT TOP 10 Id, DtPagina
FROM FullTextPagina(N'"DIEGO NUNES J COMBINADO"')
ORDER BY DtPagina DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

**EDIT 4**

Full code for `FullTextPagina`

```
USE [RexConsumo_2011_11]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[FullTextPagina]    Script Date: 11/24/2011 11:43:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FullTextPagina] (@term nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select * from Pagina as p where contains(p.PageText, @term)
)

GO
```

Comment: In the `TOP 10` case what is the "Number of Executions" value for the full text TVF (you can see this in SSMS actual execution plan by selecting the operator and viewing the properties window). Also what is the degree of parallelism for the first plan? Can you post the plan XML not just the image?

Comment: @MartinSmith, bizarre! In the top 10 case, it executes 1.18 million times, the other just 1!

Comment: I'll try to post this plan XML

Comment: On the bottom plan what is the estimated number of rows coming out of the non clustered index scan?

Comment: @MartinSmith, I'm trying to find an easy file sharing site to host the execution plan XML. Wait a moment.

Comment: @MartinSmith, edited the question to include the XML

Comment: Are you sure without the top ALL results are coming back or is it that just some are and it's streaming the results back.  By adding top you are  forcing the engine to complete the sort to ensure you get the RIGHT top 10 based on the sort. my point being the the engine may be sorting the rest still but it knows the portions rendered are "sorted" so it starts the display.

Comment: @MartinSmith your comments are desapearing. I don't know if you're deleting them

Comment: @AndréPena - Yes I left 2 that I deleted. One saying I couldn't download the plan but then I could and one asking about auto update statistics settings but I've changed my mind that that is responsible for the issue (though wouldn't harm to check if auto update stats is turned on for the table)

Comment: @AndréPena - Can you try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the `TOP 10` query or alternatively try `SELECT TOP 10 Id, DtPagina FROM FullTextPagina( N'"DIEGO NUNES J COMBINADO"') ORDER BY DtPagina DESC`

Comment: @MartinSmith Tried. No effect. Updated the question with the statements I used

Comment: @AndréPena - Does that effect the estimated number of rows coming out of the non clustered index scan at all? (was 603.84 in your original plan)

Comment: @MartinSmith, No it didn't affect. It only affected time. This time it took 2.56m to complete

Comment: @AndréPena - Please post the code for `FullTextPagina`. I somehow completely missed this was a user TVF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are getting is because SQL Server isn't accurately estimating how many rows will match the predicate.

Your query is doing `SELECT TOP 10 Id, DtPagina ... ORDER BY DtPagina DESC`. There are a couple of options as to how it could do this

#### Option 1

It could just scan the `DtPagina DESC` index in order and see if each row matches the full text predicate then exit when the first 10 in index order have been found.

#### Option 2

1. Evaluate the full text predicate
2. Retrieve the `DtPagina` column values for all the matching rows
3. Sort them and get the top 10.

When costing the first option the bottom plan shows that it expects to have to scan about 600 rows before getting 10 that match and being able to exit. This is a massive underestimate as in fact no rows match the predicate and it needs to do this for the whole 1,186,533 rows.

When costing the second option from the top plan it can be seen that it assumes that there are 13,846.2 matching rows that will be brought back from the full text index query and need to be joined and sorted. This is a large over estimate as the actual figure is zero.

So these incorrect estimates lead it to favour the first option incorrectly.

I'm not sure what can be done to improve the accuracy of the Full Text indexing statistics. Maybe try rewriting the query using `containstable`

**Edit:** This is a bit of a hack but may well work. What if you try

```
declare @term nvarchar(4000)= N'"DIEGO NUNES J COMBINADO"'
declare @num int = 10

SELECT TOP (@num) Id, DtPagina
FROM FullTextPagina(@term)
ORDER BY DtPagina DESC
```

Then it will assume `TOP 100` which may well be sufficient to tip it into choosing the other more efficient plan.

Comment: +1 For narrowing the problem by questions asked in the comments. Excellent, beautiful work!

Comment: @MartinSmith, I really appreciate your time and patience. In fact using containstable solved the problem. They're both almost instant now. However I didn't understand your answer. Why does it have to execute the TVF almost two million times just because it didn't estimate it well?

Comment: @AndréPena - Because you are ordering by `DtPagina` it figures it will be cheaper to just scan that index in order and see if each row matches the full text predicate rather than evaluate the full text predicate, find the (estimated 13,846 actual 0) matching rows then sort them and get the top 10. But this is based on the entirely incorrect assumption that it will only have to do this 600 times so it greatly underestimates the cost of that option and also overestimates the cost of the other option.